# How to use mysql-connector mysql adapter with django??/

Tags: django, pip, mysql-connector, django-mysql

I cannot use mysqlclient package in the hosting server because it is a shared hosting server and they would not let me have a root privilige!! so I found about the mysql-connector adapter, I guess it is developed by MySQL but I could not find anyone using it to connect to the database, does someone know how to use it?? please help

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you have to run the command  **`pip install mysqlclient`**
  after that change your settings.py file with this code.

  DATABASES = {
  'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
  'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
  'USER': 'root',
  'PASSWORD': 'root',
  'HOST': 'Your host',
  'PORT': 3306
  }
  }
- I think it should work for you. But would like to inform you that some of the hosting servers mostly support the **Postgresql** rather than the **MySQL** DB.

Comment: They would not let met have root access so I cannot install mysqlclient

Comment: No, there is no need to access the root to install the mysqlclient you only need to do is that just run **pip install mysqlclient** in your terminal from any code editor you use, I personally prefer **pycharm** for django projects.